# Set definition area for output of splot

Tags: gnuplot

What I want to create is a efficiency map in gnuplot. Therefore I have values (x y z) with z as the efficiency in a datafile named `efficiency_cloud.dat`.

I plot some data with `splot`. I want to show that in a 2D diagramm with the third dimension as contours. That works, but gnuplot extrapolates. I don't want to show the extrapolated part because therefore are no values in my datafile and it would physically no sense. 
Here is my code up to now:

```
view map
unset surface
set dgrid3d 25,25,2.5

set contours
set cntrparam levels incr 16,1,35

splot "efficiency_cloud.dat" using 1:2:3 with lines, "efficiency_cloud.dat" using 1:2:3 with labels
```

That makes a picture like the following where i added the pink line manually afterwards. It's just an example `y= -1.5*x+250`

Result with manually added graph as example for a border:

[image]

Is there an option to show just the part that lies under the graph?

Comment: Of course gnuplot extrapolates, because with `set dgrid3d` you explicitly tell to do so.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but it would be nice to say where it should not show the extrapolation. In this case here it is impossible to reach the area above a certain area. That's the reason why I don't want to plot there something

Comment: Ok. @bibi's approach should work, but for that to work properly you must first save the interpolated data to an intermediate file, and then plot that one with the conditional: `set dgrid3d 25,25; set table 'efficiency_cloud_smoothed.dat'; splot 'efficiency_cloud.dat' u 1:2:3; unset table; unset dgrid3d; splot 'efficiency_cloud_smoothed.dat' u ...`.

Comment: Yeah that was also my idea now. And then it works! But I have a problem with the labels. How can I add them? And especially add them at the correct place (not over the graph)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours I found a solution: We first need to use `set table` and `splot`the contours. To make sure they are only visible in a certain area we create two functions (upper and lower limit) with `fit` in combination with many parameters, so our functions fits really well.

So now we plot with conditions as [@bibi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2743307/bibi) already sayed. So solve the problem with the labels we use the little parameter `every`.

[image: Efficiency map with gnuplot]

So here it is:

```
unset key
unset xtics

unset ytics

set view map
unset surface
set dgrid3d 15,15,2.5

# create contours
set contours
set cntrparam cubicspline
set cntrparam levels discrete 20, 24, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35

# create file
set table 'contours_eta'
splot [0:100] "data_efficiency.dat" using 1:2:3 with lines
unset table

unset dgrid3d

# define styles
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb 'black'
set style textbox opaque margins  0.5,  0.5 noborder 
set style line 2  lt 0 lc rgb '#0025ad' dt 11 lw 1    

# upper limit
f0(x) = at0 + bt0*x + ct0*x**2 + dt0*x**3 + et0*x**5 + ft0*x**6 + gt0*x**7
fit [0:100] f0(x) "file_with_points_for_upper_limit.dat" using 1:2 \
via at0,bt0,ct0,dt0,et0,ft0,gt0

# lower limit
g0(x) = ab0 + bb0*x + cb0*x**2 + db0*x**3 + eb0*x**5 + fb0*x**6 + gb0*x**7
fit [0:100] g0(x) "file_with_points_for_lower_limit.dat" using 1:2 \
via ab0,bb0,cb0,db0,eb0,fb0,gb0

# variable for the density of the labels
incr = 40

plot [0:80] [0:250] "file_with_points_for_upper_limit.dat" w l ls 1,\
  "file_with_points_for_lower_limit.dat" w l ls 1,\
  for [n=0:20] 'contours_eta' index (n) u 1:((f0($1) > $2) && (g0($1) < $2)) ? $2 : 0/0 ls 2 w l,\
  'contours_eta' index 0:20 every incr u 1:(((f0($1) > $2) && (g0($1) < $2)) ? $2 : 0/0):(((f0($1) > $2) && (g0($1) < $2)) ? $3 : 0/0) w labels center boxed
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT :

As suggested in a comment by [@Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604213/christoph), you need to store to a file the contours and then filter those points you don't want

```
reset
set view map
unset key
unset surface
set dgrid3d 25,25,2.5
set contour
set cntrparam levels incr 16,1,35

set table "contours.dat"
splot "efficieny_cloud.txt" u 1:2:3 with lines
unset table
unset dgrid
unset contour
set surface

f(x)=-1.5*x+250

splot 'contours.dat' u 1:2:(f($1)<$2?0/0:0) w l
```

or

```
plot "contours.dat" u 1:(f($1) > $2 ? $2: 0/0) with lines
```

or

```
stats'efficieny_cloud.txt'
g(x)=STATS_max_y
plot "contours.dat" u 1:2 w l, "+" u 1:(f(x)):(g(x)) w filledcur
```

Apparently you loose the possibility of adding the labels as it would mean to mix contour/non-contour, dgrid/non-dgrid and surface/nonsurface.

And saving in a table the plot with only labels, doesn't just save the labal-points (you can request gnuplot-devs to implement such a thing, it shouldn't be so difficult to do)

Comment: Unfortunately your first alternative doesn't work. The second way it not suitable for me, because the function will be a higher dimensional function and making a polygon will be ... hard.

Comment: Could you post somewhere the data, so that I can ceck why the frist solution is not working?

Comment: Yeah I could do this. Is there a common place/hoster for that?

Comment: No, not at all: http://pastebin.com/Ju6WhYgG (don't wonder i will look different, I manipulated som parameters...)

Comment: Great thanks. I also found a solution to plot the labels: I create with the programm that creates also the raw value a file with points in correct position and correct z value. Then I use `set table 'labels'` and later `replot 'labels' using 1:2:3 with labels`. That's great, thanks. 

BUT: Unfortunately I realized that my graph will be raw data and no function like in the used `f(x)=-1.5*x+250`. `fit` finds no suitable function, so I guess it is impossible to realize it now...?